# Meaning of Use in Build option in Visual Studions Build Events

Tags: visual-studio

What is the use case of setting `Use in Build: No` in the Visual Studios Build Events? In this case, the build event do not execute when I build the project.

[image]

Comment: That build event may be configuration-dependent: use it in (say) the Debug build but not in the Release build (or *vice versa*).